# Multiple voltage level on multiple rail using ORing PMIC

Tags: power-supply, power-management

I have two voltage rail that i would like to have 4 different voltage levels 0v, 5v, V1, V2. where V1 and V2 are anywhere from 6v to 60v. The two voltage rail can have any of the voltage at any time.

So far I have come up of two schematic design, both i some uncertainties with.

[image]

First off the PMIC i am using is the [LM7602](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm76202-q1.pdf) Which is a must have in my application because of Over voltage, Under Voltage, Reverse voltage, Over Current protections

how 0v and 5v on both rail is handled is: Not in the schematics are two 5v PMIC with basically the same feautures as the LM6202. So to create 5v, the 5v PMIC is enable and the raile chosen will have its LM76202 is turned to shutdown giving the rail 5v. 0 is kinda opposite of 5v where the 5v pmic is disable and the rail chosen is also disabled (there are two 5v PMIC, one for each rail)

V1 and V2 are user plugged voltage assumed to be 6v to 60v (and is protected by UVLO,OVP,RVP). On the left schematic basically there can be a max of 2 LM76202 enable at a given time and each rail has 2 LM76202 which are connetected to V1 and V2. depending on what the rail is set two v1 or v2 can be enabled. Now my problem with this is it seems to be a waste of IC since only a max of 2 can be used at any given time and this IC does not come cheap (5$) making 3pieces of this board is already 60$ on that ic alone.

The schematics on the right seems to be a more economical option by using 2 P channel mosfet like [FDS8935](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDS8935-D.PDF) to switch the loads to other rail. The disadvantage of this is, one im not confident if the circuit is correctly made, and two, the rail will have to share the current limit of the other rail.

Is there any better way to achieve the multiple voltage on 2 rails that i require? My voltage range for V1 and V2 are 6-60v at max 2A. The 5v is set to 500mA each rail.

Comment: Circuit 2 doesn't allow V2 onto rail1 AND V1 onto rail 2.

Comment: @Andyaka Hello good sir?  Why would it not work ? Is something wrong on how i made the PMOS switch ?

Comment: You can’t simultaneously swap voltages. Think about it.

Comment: @Andyaka you are right, I cant switch at certain situations, for like when rail 2 is set to 5v i cannot set rail 1 to v2 because that would mean changing rail 2 also. Now that i even look at it i cannot even drive those PMOS beyond 20v of input

Comment: @Andyaka the left side is just so expensive, How do different voltage on the rail is done typically which out using mechanical relays, USB C does it but only upto 20v

Comment: It uses a switching regulator to dial in the voltage as far as I know. Maybe you need to take a step back and describe what you want rather than what you think you should do.